# Who should manage if there are the required/valid (URL) parameters in MVC/Zend Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, web-applications

For example, if my controller action expects an integer "id" parameter, what should ensure that requirement is met?

Maybe in the Controller Action do something like the below?

```
 if (isset($this->_getParam("id")) && is_numeric($this->_getParam("id"))) { ... }
```

Then what about whether the id is valid? eg. the row does not exists in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply by using

```
$validator  = new Zend_Validate_Digits();
$id = $this->_getParam("id") ; 
$valid = $validator->isValid($id);
if($valid){
  // its valid number 
}else{
// its not valid number 
}
```

and if the id is exist or not exist in the db , there is some [validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) 
this example uses zend_db , you can write your custom validator

```
//Check that the email address exists in the database
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'emailaddress'
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid($emailaddress)) {
    // email address appears to be valid
} else {
    // email address is invalid; print the reasons
    foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are two steps...

1. Validation of the given Data like you did or via form validation
2. Checking for a corresponding row in the DB via SQL or Model instanstiation

`$row = $db->fetchRow($db->select()->where('ID= ?', $id));`

`echo count($row); // check count`

`echo !empty($row); // untested ...should work to`

Comment: In other words, you are saying it should be done in the controller? I was wondering if at least the validation of the existance and type of a parameter can be done using routers (regex route perhaps)

Comment: In one word, YES, in the controller. And the solution of tawfekov is even cleaner.. you could use one validator for the input and a second to validate the DB entry.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your controllers should be able to handle any data that comes via the url. Typically, I validate the relevance of the data (ie, is it a legit database id, name, command, etc?) before I do anything with it. I've never really felt the need for baseline type validation on url arguments. Testing for NULLs is certainly a good idea, although `getParam` does allow you to specify a default should the value be null.

Anyway, here's how I would do this if I had to. **Note: I haven't actually tested this code. It's all 'in theory'.**

I would pass type information into the `defaults` array of my route object.

```
// assuming you're using an ini config for routes
routes.myroute.defaults.arg_types.id[] = 'integer'

// so your 'defaults' array will looks like:

Array(
  [controller] => mycontroller
  [action] => myactions
  [arg_types] => Array 
  (
      [id] => Array
      (
          [0] => notnull
          [1] => integer 
      )

  )

)
```

Then I would write a Controller plugin that validates each argument based on the config data we've specified during the dispatch loop:

```
public function preDispatch($request)
{
    $params = $request->getParams();
    $route = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute();
    $type_args = $route->getDefault('type_args');


    foreach($params as $param) {
      if (!in_array($param, $type_args)) {
        continue;
      }

      foreach($type_args[$param] as $type) {
        switch($type) {
          case 'notnull':
             // validate for null
             break;
          case 'integer':
             // validate for integer
             break;
          // etc.
        }
      }
    }


}
```

Obviously, there is quite a bit more logic to be handled here, such as what to do when things don't validate.